# mouseDown event in a custom view does not show correct coordinates of the click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I have a custom view class, which receives the mouse events. I do not get correct coordinates of the mouseDown or mouseUp events. No matter where I click inside the view, I get the same incorrect coordinates.

This is the function I have in my Custom NSView class

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSPoint coordinateInBaseWindow = theEvent.locationInWindow;
    
    NSPoint coordinateInView = [self convertPoint:coordinateInBaseWindow fromView:nil];
    NSLog(@"left mouse down (x,y) =(%f,%f)", coordinateInView.x, coordinateInView.y);
}
```

I have a similar handler of `mouseUp` event.

Now the output is always

> left mouse down (x,y) =(0.000000,-1.996910)
>
> left mouse up (x,y) =(0.000000,0.000000)

No matter where I click inside the view, the coordinate of left mouse down is always (0.000000,-1.996910) and left mouse up is always (0.000000,0.000000).

1. What am I doing wrong? Why I am unable to get correct coordinates of the mouse click event?
2. mouseDown and mouseUp together makes one click. Shouldn't the coordinates of the mouseDown and mouseUp equal? Why are they different in this case?

**Edit 1:**

As [omz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8488652/177116) pointed out, I should have used `convertPoint:fromView:` but this too has not solved the problem. I am still getting the same coordinates.

**Edit 2:**
My format specifiers in NSLog were incorrect which were giving me totally wrong results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert *from* window coordinates you have to use `convertPoint:fromView:` with `nil` as the view parameter. Your conversion does the opposite.

Comment: I have fixed the code but I am still getting the same result. `(0.000000,-1.996910)` and `(0.000000,0.000000)`.

Comment: Your (edited) code works fine here. Anything else in your code that could affect the result?